# Xcode- Chartboost SDK not showing any messages in log

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, chartboost

I am trying to get v3.2 of Chartboost SDK working on Xcode 4.6.2 on iPhone 6.1 (Retina 4-Inch) simulator with Base SDK 6.1 and Deployment Target of iOS 6.0.

However there are NO messages being logged at all in the log output (and no ads showing either)... no messages as to whether or not the startSession was succesful, no messages as to whether the ad failed to load or not.

I am using NSLogs to verify that the startSession and showInterstitial are being called.

The app id and signature are correct and there is a campaign setup (I am using these from existing live app).

Anybody else had any strange issues with the chartboost sdk like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so apparently Chartboost support tells me that their SDK does not actually show anything in the log output (v3.2). They have added it as a future feature request.

And for the ads, in the Chartboost dashboard under APPs you can set the app orientation for either landscape or portrait or both. I had orientation set to landscape but app was portrait so no ads will show when these do not match.

So it was a PEBKAC error.